# How do I merge TensorFlow Dataset columns into (features, label) tuple for Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I have a `tf.data.Dataset` consisting of multiple fields (e.g. feature1, feature2, feature3, label). How do I convert it into a `Tensor` with (features, label) that I can pass to `Keras` for model training?

**UPDATE**

The `tf.data.Dataset` is a dictionary of like:

```
{
    'feature1': 1.5,
    'feature2': 5.6,
    'feature3': 7.9,
    'label': 1.0
}
```

The expected `Keras` input format is a `tuple` with two tensors `(features_tensor, label_tensor)`.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Please provide some minimal reproducible code so that we can understand what you mean by "(e.g. feature1, feature2, feature3, label)".

Comment: so here is the thing... there is a lot of custom proprietary infrastructure around this...

Comment: To be clear: is this one element of `tf.data.dataset` object which you want to transform, or is it an element from a Python list of dictionaries?

Comment: one element of `tf.data.dataset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function which could take the dictionary element and return the data as a tuple in the desired format. Then, you can use [`tf.data.Dataset.map`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) method to apply it on your dataset:

```
def reformat_element(elem):
    features = [elem['feature1'], elem['feature2'], elem['feature3']]
    label = [elem['label']]
    return features, label

dataset = dataset.map(reformat_element)
```